# How to fix this file `s' not found error in python?

Tags: python

```
import patoolib
patoolib.create_archive("file.zip", ("to_pdf.pdf"))
```

and on running i am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\happy\Desktop\Site_Blocker\file_to_archive.py", line 2, in <module>
    patoolib.create_archive("file.zip", ("to_pdf.pdf"))
  File "C:\Users\happy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\patoolib\__init__.py", line 712, in create_archive
    util.check_archive_filelist(filenames)
  File "C:\Users\happy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\patoolib\util.py", line 422, in check_archive_filelist
    check_existing_filename(filename, onlyfiles=False)
  File "C:\Users\happy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\patoolib\util.py", line 398, in check_existing_filename
    raise PatoolError("file `%s' was not found" % filename)
patoolib.util.PatoolError: file `t' was not found
```

Please tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: You probably meant `("to_pdf.pdf",)` - note the comma.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument of `create_archive` is the filenames. You appear to be trying to give it a tuple, which would work, but the syntax that you have used is not correct for creating a one-element tuple.

`("to_pdf.pdf")` will evaluate to simply `"to_pdf.pdf"`, and when you iterate over this string you will get the *characters* in the string, hence the error on the first iteration that there is no file called `t`.

To create a one-element tuple, you should include the comma:

```
patoolib.create_archive("file.zip", ("to_pdf.pdf",))
```

Alternatively, you could use a list:

```
patoolib.create_archive("file.zip", ["to_pdf.pdf"])
```